# Flutter and .aar

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, aar

Has enyone a complete step-by-step guide, how to import .aar file to a Flutter project, and use it?
All guides i find are 2-5 years old.
Flutter 2.10.0, Dart 2.16, Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Thanks for any help!

Comment: could you expand more into what your need? What have you tried so far? Could you show code and/or implementations? Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic as requesting for libraries, guides, etc is Off-Topic for StackOverFlow.

Comment: I have an aar package from an individual manufacturer. Only aar, no code, no gradle, no maven. In this aar are some functions, for a specially printer. I want to call this functions from my Flutter application (Android)

Comment: @BenedekKörtvélyesi any solution?

Comment: @BenedekKörtvélyesi hi, did you find any solution for this?